# GET request [status code 404] Amazon Product API

Tags: python, web-scraping, amazon-product-api, get-request, csrf-token

I'm trying to send a GET request to this URL but I'm getting status code 404

[SOURCE_URL](https://data.amazon.it/api/marketplaces/APJ6JRA9NG5V4/deals/a4e00097,9c91c27e,7a475971,9800e513,2829d091,c9280e8c,d982787d,7f2e4067,59f38bcb,f3d04636,07d6f3c0,c90c7069,9b103423,a187250b,b0725bd1,d542c309,225ffbf5,a70e896c,16bcaa86,e4a9fef5,3300ae7d,25c13fc2,8212dee8,23a2b0d0,0b97015a,68f59214,8b5662ef,7ed16bc9,1f2c4cff,aaa2b7e6)

I got the x-api-csrf-token from my browser...could this be the reason why i get status code 404?

If that's the problem, I was thinking of doing it this way:
Send a GET request to the mainPage[the page that display the data], collect cookies, extract the x-api-csrf-token from the response content, send a GET request to the API adding the token and cookies to the headers.

This is the code I'm using:

```
import requests

url = "https://data.amazon.it/api/marketplaces/APJ6JRA9NG5V4/deals/a4e00097,9c91c27e,7a475971,9800e513,2829d091,c9280e8c,d982787d,7f2e4067,59f38bcb,f3d04636,07d6f3c0,c90c7069,9b103423,a187250b,b0725bd1,d542c309,225ffbf5,a70e896c,16bcaa86,e4a9fef5,3300ae7d,25c13fc2,8212dee8,23a2b0d0,0b97015a,68f59214,8b5662ef,7ed16bc9,1f2c4cff,aaa2b7e6"

payload = ""
headers = {
    "cookie": "session-id=257-4653422-6386726; session-id-time=2082787201l; i18n-prefs=EUR; session-token=%22heptZl%2FZVeqrBWcUituH5ogwcXUotvtpbIL9ef0GEO%2Fp3xPgPsDH8e39x43ablKkulC1mM1DiseB7YwSPBeGtAl6bMamJHS5eME33KAjjbVXNA2YNLsE9KMKCphDOjA3QJfD%2FTkM%2Bb3NLXB4pYAUjbDiVjFb1o3rtGxb5G12ANllHXBa328O0KAo2Tqon%2FhITXXNyPPQc1IcC6NWgZkST3kIJajDEunZyq1VRl6bX6k%3D%22; ubid-acbit=258-2384847-5117422",
    "Host": "data.amazon.it",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:107.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/107.0",
    "Accept": "application/vnd.com.amazon.api+json; type="collection(deal/v1)/v1"; expand="details(deal.details/v1),status(deal.status/v1),badge(deal.badge/v1)"; experiments="DealBadgeColors_4da10b4,DealBadgeRounding_8c426ad,DealLabelType_05035b,DealMessageType_024db1"",
    "Accept-Language": "it-IT",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Referer": "https://www.amazon.it/",
    "Origin": "https://www.amazon.it",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Cookie": "session-id=262-3152518-0586920; session-id-time=2082787201l; i18n-prefs=EUR; ubid-acbit=258-0859323-6638749; session-token="p/ss9wKZeGOGoYBtZK8+t0rT6F5L3YTC8Z4k6Cnlcgle4tU5Gzd3fg6zxkTUQVV/Z5tZ6vILGLJhHzcQ9rUB6ySpy28m2bV6ts9e94z2dTaCudz2CfCKZYAGIlqo4h+Qp2bTlxGjRDfPfP9sOhPCMsVsJtHl9+6enak15XarNxLDhYuCPJ+KjyWfw+VSp0Rt1oSj89UvMqX2L4QD8Q9g0HHhIjen71gQB6WhhbvbXIBMQQYVRGBpiQ=="; s_fid=419262F6CBE7FA10-2B627CC84A6F0EC9; x-acbit="@xb6H3x7PwxIaUm2bSsZOSUNw4lNHWjwDZLdcBC8BHaSDSwus8tnlP8UBhCxQFlH"; at-acbit=Atza|IwEBIBRTNqvpSWqH4Ul_FTm16ukMYOTHz5jHPzK372ZPWz9-yq_L0xl38hQKecIp8G1eFMrdouCNB1kCkV54nY6h_8wucHcE5lxR9qg6gX2rYh8NEHw44q4Il44N-J3nwOLicu4_tgYWC1gZLZb4p5zBenoBJh3csco5N7vfcJDwNpI4lb7DgvwE9yHcTYyFxrNndGCB_uOmjKVbHBOdlDMEqR_3qQPDPVqqMrhwnfvOgCdKyw; sess-at-acbit="MFmRZH4Jiw9U6NCXBCPvOt+tshDQcRp/Y0RUDZZhrQQ="; sst-acbit=Sst1|PQHrPfyNVhBTJzqHDKvL_B2uCQJg0_C2fdGuNWXlW8t26uTtHcM0Z81Vg5tJQMebk1MZDOUytb1REGDqh9gLx8QrCMQrDcYcEjr6dztrPaSjDLJQczzo4kpZMsAM1wxoZ9Aq40WNNEfOVVWDVrFE-KWLMETE5EihzkwiULqw71rjgvDZ4-GMh3Hfp1eLLGoFYToG05tqtdEVjoU83Ctiahey9fIbyVSn5vVwsh2rjxrt9J3DtmBHhMiM5vVoodKoWmNQjDcvAbwbONCqlw_siELpjqQbBaGHJDK3nOXL8qJ_akE",
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "no-cors",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-site",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "x-api-csrf-token": "1@gzQI/o7Ej7rVuwddQPykqGYTQCgCeiUKupgsgsKtYX/LAAAAAQAAAABjei9+cmF3AAAAAGfA1H5nd8xGEcC34HqGsA==@THOB0T",
    "x-cc-currency-of-preference": "EUR",
    "Pragma": "no-cache",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

Comment: 404 error means the server does not know about that url.  Are you absolutely sure that url is correct?

Comment: Yes, I copied the URL from the request sent by my browser, I also tried to disable the x-csrf token from that request and I'm getting the same status code [404]

Comment: Why are you sending a GET request with a data payload?  Typically only POST requests have payloads.  And why a content-type: application/json header, when you are clearly not sending json?

Comment: The code that you see above is generated by httpsnippet, I'm using insomnia.rest because it is easier to manipulate request parameters.